# creating property dynamically in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.subjectname[$index]" 
   name="subject" ng-required="true" placeholder="Enter a subject name">
   </div>
```

As I am creating this input field dynamically using ng-repeat, if I used `ng-model=user.subjectname`, the input text for some reason was same in all the fields, I searched over the internet and found `ng-model="user.subjectname[$index]"`   being used and it worked.

However, i am not able to understand

1. what it exactly means.  ?

2.If it's array or an object. ?

3. It shows up as object in console. ?
4. If it's object, why does it have an index?

Also, as we can iterate over object vals using this format:

```
ng-repeat="(key,val) in user.subjectname"{{val}}
```

Why did it not work?

```
neither did ng-repeat="subject in user.subjectname"{{subject}}
```

Can  I please get directions as I am very confused about it at the moment.

Comment: Just add `{{ user.subjectname | json }}` outside of ngRepeat and you will see that Angular populates array for you.

Comment: here using first approach which is ng-model=user.subjectname, you are attaching same model for all of the text input. and changed made in any of the text box will update model and hence update all of the textbox. but using $index you are creating array of independent model and attaching to the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an array. When you do :

```
var test = []; console.info(typeof test);// You would get object as arraysa re also object in Javascript.
```

Here you are passing $index of choice in choices to subjectname array. Which is fine. After populating subjectname with some of the data, you can use ng-repeat like

```
ng-repeat = "subject in user.subjectname"
```

Also initialize user.subjectname = []; in controller

Comment: I had thought I could do this and should work but user.subjectname gave something like this {0:'Math', 1:'sCience}

Comment: Initialize user.subjectname in controller as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="idea item">
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in items[0]" >
    <label>{{key}}</label>
    <input type="range" ng-model="items[0][key]" min="0" max="15"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" ng-click="save()" />
<pre>{{items | json}}</pre>
```

var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {
})

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{"red": 14, "green": 12, "orange": 1, "yellow": 11, "blue": 9}];
})
```